# Correct and better way to customize wordpress theme or/and plugins without lose my changes after un update

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

i have a theme or a plugin, and i decided to edit it.
My trouble is that when i update it (for example the theme's author release an update) i lose my changes, because the update overwrite the theme files (or plugin files).
What is the solution ? Child Theme for the theme ? How works it ? And for Plugins ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned, I would set up a child theme.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

Comment: It is not recommended to make changes to a plugin as your changes will be overridden with an update and your code might work in current version but break in future versions of the plugin.